# Playwright test will only pass when debugging, but fails when running when testing angular app

Tags: angular, playwright

I have some basic playwright tests I'm writing, and they work completely as expected when I'm debugging.  It's just checking that an element exists within a div.  When I run the test without debugging it's coming back having not found that element.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Tests:

```
let someHomePage: SomeHomePage;

test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
    someHomePage = new SomeHomePage(page);
    await someHomePage.goto();
});

test('This is my sample test', async ({page}) => {
    expect(await Utils.elementExistsBelowInDiv(page, 'myDivClass', 'p', 'Some text', 'h4', 'Some text')).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Utils class method:

```
static async elementExistsBelowInDiv(page: Page, className: string, elementAbove: string, textAbove: string, elementBelow: string, textBelow: string) : Promise<boolean> {
    const element = page.locator(`.${className}`).locator(`${elementAbove}:has-text("${textAbove}"):below(${elementBelow}:has-text("${textBelow}"))`);
    return await element.count() > 0;
}
```

When I'm debugging this code, it finds the element find and returns a count > 0.  When I run the test without debugging, the test fails because toBeTruthy() returns false.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try adding await where you are locating the element in the page in elementExistsBelowInDiv()?

Comment: Yeah that didn't change anything.  VS Code also gave a "warning"(?) stating that putting an await there has no affect on that line of code

Comment: Can you share the HTML elements involved please? Maybe I can help you with a locator.

Answer (score 2):

I faced some similar issues with my work. I found out that the action I am trying to do requires some loading or waiting time but the playwright does the action so fast it doesn't wait for the load. So when you use debugging the process gets the waiting time while running the test don't wait. I solved my problem using

```
waitUntil: 'networkidle'
```

you can also use [this](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-load-state) method for the wait. This will solve the problem of running the test and getting the expected result.